# How to add a text file content to the next column of an existing table

Tags: linux, command-line, table

How do a add a new line to an existing .txt file, that consists of a text string, a tab, and a value of another text file?

Precisely, I have a text file `test1.txt` that looks like this:

```
A    B
```

and a `test2.txt` file that only contains the number value 100.

What I want to do is to use a command by which I would edit the `test1.txt` file, and make it look like this:

```
A    B
C    100
```

I've tried using the following command:

```
echo -e "C \t" test2.txt>>test1.txt.
```

I know that by using the command

```
test2.txt>>test1.txt
```

I will add a new row to `test1.txt`, with the value of 100, but what I'm trying to do is to add that value as a next column as I wish to make a table with data.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ printf %s $'C\t'; cat test2.txt; } >>test1.txt
```

or

```
( printf %s $'C\t'; cat test2.txt ) >>test1.txt
```

or

```
printf %s $'C\t' >>test1.txt
cat test2.txt    >>test1.txt
```

or in bash

```
{ printf %s $'C\t'"$(<test2.txt)"; } >>test1.txt
```